# Why do I have a segmentation fault in my link list?

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

After I would input the first number it says segmentation fault and I don't know why. My goal is to make a link list where I have a root to be a certain number and would input greater numbers that will be eventually be added to part of the link list. For example, the root / the first number will be 50. I would add a greater number 60 that will be added to another node further down the lin list. The process will repeat as I assume the numbers inputted will get greater and greater.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{

  int num;
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;

}
node;

int main(void){

  printf("Put in a number:");
  int x = 0;
  scanf("%i", x);

  node* a = malloc(sizeof(node));
  a->num = x;
  node* temp = a;

  int n = 1;
  while(n == 1){
    
    printf("Put in another number:");
    int y = 0;
    scanf("%i", y);

    while(n == 1){
      
      if (temp->num < y){
        if (temp->right == NULL){
          node* a = malloc(sizeof(node));
          temp->right = a;
          temp->right->num = y;
          break;
        }
        else{
          temp = temp->right;
        }
      }
    
    printf("Want to stop? Yes(1) or No (1)?");
    scanf("%i", n);
    
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of the calls of scanf

```
scanf("%i", x);
scanf("%i", y);
scanf("%i", n);
```

is incorrect. You have to pass the variables  by reference

```
scanf("%i", &x);
scanf("%i", &y);
scanf("%i", &n);
```

This while loop

```
while(n == 1){
  
  if (temp->num < y){
    if (temp->right == NULL){
      node* a = malloc(sizeof(node));
      temp->right = a;
      temp->right->num = y;
      break;
    }
    else{
      temp = temp->right;
    }
  }

printf("Want to stop? Yes(1) or No (1)?");
scanf("%i", n);

}
```

can invoke undefined behavior because for a newly allocated node

```
    if (temp->right == NULL){
      node* a = malloc(sizeof(node));
      temp->right = a;
      temp->right->num = y;
      break;
    }
```

you are not setting its data member `right` to `NULL`. So it has indeterminate value. As a result this if statement

```
    if (temp->right == NULL){
```

after this statement

```
      temp = temp->right;
```

compares this indeterminate value with `NULL`.

And it seems there is a typo in the outputted string

```
printf("Want to stop? Yes(1) or No (1)?");
                        ^^^^       ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue would probably be avoided enabling warning in your compiler (`-Wall` for GCC). **Always** check warnings, even when it seems that the compilation progresses anyway (which can be avoided with `-W error`).

By calling `scanf ()` you are saying to your program: *"Read the input from `stdin`, an if it matches the format specifier I defined store it to a specific address"*.

So basically it expects an address for each format specifier you pass it.

With

```
scanf("%i", x);
```

you are passing `x`, that is not an address, so `scanf` will *try* to write there causing a *segmentation fault* because it will likely be an invalid address, not belonging to the *segment* assigned by the OS to your process.

You want instead pass *the address of `x`*, using unary operator `&`:

```
scanf("%i", &x);
```

(the same mistake is repeated when you call `scanf` for `y` and `n` variables)

Comment: Yep, you already got my nod, so I'm tapped out. May be worth finding out what compiler is being used. Then we could show how to enable warnings, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` or `/W3` for VS, etc..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin actually my guess is that wanings are shown but ignored

Comment: The old "Lead a horse to water, but can't make him drink" issue `:)`